# Funnel of events i Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a set up with a lots of events tracking a videoplayer.

I would like to figure out how many users that watch more than 1 video, and how many users that watch ie. videos in the car-category and then watch something in the entertainment-category.

Anyone know if there is a nice way to do this? I've played with custom reports and with Content Flow but can't really figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried the Funnel beta that lets you build a report based on sequences of events?

Comment: Thanks! Is this found in Behavior > Events > Events Flow? Same as Analytics MI talks about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event flow reports to see the require data. Behavior > Events > Events Flow.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try! =D